# nested serializer not returning expected values Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I've started learning django recently and can't seem to figure out how to get the data I want. I'm looking to build an object that can give me each part name and all of the reports of that part and then get the report data but only for the part I'm currently on

This is an example of the data I would want.

```py
{
    "count": 2536,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/esd/salesreportsdetail2/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "A0012",
            "sales_report_parts": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "date": "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
                    "sales_report_items": [
                        {
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "site": "FBA"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 3,
                            "site": "Vendor"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 4,
                            "site": "Main"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But instead, I keep getting all the sales report items for each item.

```py
{
    "count": 2536,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/esd/salesreportsdetail2/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "A0012",
            "sales_report_parts": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "date": "2021-08-31T00:00:00Z",
                    "sales_report_items": [
                        {
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "site": "FBA"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 3,
                            "site": "Vendor"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 4,
                            "site": "Main"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 45,
                            "site": "FBA"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 102,
                            "site": "Vendor"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 161,
                            "site": "Main"
                        },
                        {
                            "quantity": 7,
                            "site": "FBA"
                        },... and so on gets me all of the data
```

Below are my models, views, and serializer. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance!

models.py

```py
    class SalesReport(models.Model):
        month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False)
        year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False)
        date = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        parts = models.ManyToManyField(
            "Part", through="SalesReportItem", related_name="sales_report_parts"
        )

    class SalesReportItem(models.Model):
        part = models.ForeignKey(
            "Part", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sales_report_part"
        )
        quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False)
        site = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SITE_CHOICES, null=False)
        sales_report = models.ForeignKey(
            SalesReport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sales_report_items"
        )

    class Part(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        crea`enter code here`ted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
        sales_reports = models.ManyToManyField(
            SalesReport, through="SalesReportItem", related_name="part_sales_report"
        )
```

views.py

```py
class SalesReportDetailViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SalesReport.objects.prefetch_related("sales_report_items__part").all()
    serializer_class = SalesReportDetailSerializer


class SalesReportDetailViewSet2(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Part.objects.prefetch_related(
        "sales_report_parts__sales_report_items"
    ).all()
    serializer_class = PartDetailSerializer
    pagination_class = TestPagination
```

serializers.py

```py
class SalesReportItemDetailSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesReportItem
        fields = ["quantity", "site"]


class SalesReportDetailSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sales_report_items = SalesReportItemDetailSerializer2(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SalesReport
        fields = ["id", "date", "sales_report_items"]


class PartDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sales_report_parts = SalesReportDetailSerializer2(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ["id", "name", "sales_report_parts"]
```

Comment: Hey just curious, why was the m2m was defined twice between part and sales report?

Comment: Honestly, because I don't know how to query that relationship any other way but I also just figured that sales reports have many parts and each part has many sales reports so it made sense to me. Any other way you'd go about it?